# Angular interpolation, ng-bind and ng-translate unexpected behaviour

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, ng-bind, angularjs-interpolate

I am seeing unexpected behaviour differences when using Angular interpolation {{ blah }} as opposed to ng-bind='blah' *when using ng-translate*.  So given a really simple controller with

```
$scope.name = "Angular"
```

the following works perfectly using both interpolation and ng-bind ..

```
<div>Interpolation : Hello {{ name }}</div>
<div>ng-bind       : Hello <span ng-bind="name"/></div>
```

outputting

```
Interpolation : Hello Angular
ng-bind : Hello Angular
```

Now, introduce **ng-translate**, first setup simple translation table ..

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
  'WELCOME-INTERPOLATE': 'Hello {{ name }}',
  'WELCOME-BIND': 'Hello <span ng-bind="name"/>'
});
```

and then

```
<span translate translate-values="{name: name}">WELCOME-INTERPOLATE</span>
<span translate translate-values="{name: name}">WELCOME-BIND</span>
```

which produces

```
Hello Angular                     <-- This is interpolate
Hello                             <-- This is ng-bind and **fails**
```

and then by adding 'translate-compile' which as I understand it removes the need for 'translate-values' and gives 'translate' access to its parent scope, the same HTML with 'translate-compile' replacing 'translate-values'

```
<span translate translate-compile>WELCOME-INTERPOLATE</span>
<span translate translate-compile>WELCOME-BIND</span>
```

produces opposite result

```
Hello                             <-- This is interpolate and **fails**
Hello Angular                     <-- This is ng-bind
```

See my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8jKt26Rq7q3BOgcTWIh?p=preview) for example

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in github:

> Everything is working as expected.
>
> Either you had missed the value or HTML (aka templates which should be
>   parsed) missed the compile flag.
>
> See the plunkr

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/987